# Unir dos tabla sin duplicar los resultados, solo los elementos que le pertenecen

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada usuarios con los campos: id,nombre,appelidos,email
y tengo otra tabla llamada lugares con los campos: id,fila,asiento,idusuario.

Un usuario puede tener uno o muchos lugares.
Quiero hacer que la consulta me muestre solo los lugares que le pertenecen a cierto usuario, por ejemplo con el id 3, pero el problema es que me muestra todos los usuarios.

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
        INNER JOIN lugares    
WHERE usuarios.id = lugares.idusuario;
```

Comment: @PatricioMoracho error mio, ya lo corregí

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que buscas algo así:

```
SELECT * 
       FROM usuarios
       INNER JOIN lugares    
           ON usuarios.id = lugares.idusuario;
       WHERE usuarios.id = 3
```

- `JOIN` entre `usuarios` y `lugares` por el `id`del usuario
- Filtro por `id = 3` mediante el `WHERE`

Comment: Genial! funciono, Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

un asiento puede ser ocupado por 1 o más usuarios? ya que al tener el asiento como clave foránea al usuario, permite eso. A menos que sea a través del tiempo.

Comment: Un usuario puede registrar varios asientos o lugares con el mismo correo electronico.

Comment: Favor de no usar la zona de respuestas para hacer preguntas o comentarios

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]